# Asp.net Core does not serialize my new type

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

Am using .net core +angular 5, and trying to return a list, but one field is **null** in JSON response. Am using Postman to trigger debugging and saw in VS that the field has a value coming from the DB. 
Don't know why it doesn't in the JSON response.

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<HikingTrail> HikingTrails()
{
    var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HikingTrailContext>();
            dbOptions.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = HikingApp");
    var dbContext = new DAO.HikingTrailContext(dbOptions.Options);
    return dbContext.HikingTrails.ToList();
}
```

This returns:
I'm interested in the "***mountainRange***" field not being null. In debug window it has the right value.

> {
>           "url": null,
>           "hikingTrailId": 159,
>           *"**mountainRange**": null,*
>           "name": "My custom name",
>           "startPoint": null,
>           "endPoint": null,
>           "trailCheckpoints": null,
>           "type": 2,
>           "dificulty": null,
>           "duration": "2 1/2 - 3 h",
>           "minDuration": "00:00:00",
>           "maxDuration": "00:00:00",
>           "seasonality": "mediu",
>           "equipmentLevel": null,
>           "trailMarking": null,
>           "hasTrailType": false
>       },

I was thinking maybe it's EF Core, and have made this 2nd try (i.e. added Include() to dbContext query):

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<HikingTrail> HikingTrails()
{
    var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HikingTrailContext>();
    dbOptions.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = HikingApp");
    var dbContext = new DAO.HikingTrailContext(dbOptions.Options);
    return dbContext.HikingTrails.Include( x => x.MountainRange).ToList();
}
```

Could not get any response in **Postman**.

EDIT:

```
public class HikingTrailContext : DbContext
{
    public HikingTrailContext(DbContextOptions<HikingTrailContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public HikingTrailContext():base(){


    }

    public DbSet<HikingTrail> HikingTrails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MountainRange> MountainRanges { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrailScrapingSessionInfo> TrailScrapingHistory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}

public class HikingTrail
{
    [Key]
    public int HikingTrailId { get; set; }
    public HikingTrail() { }

    public MountainRange MountainRange { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Location StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Location EndPoint { get; set; }
    public List<Location> TrailCheckpoints { get; }
    public TrailType Type => TrailType.Undetermined;
    public String Dificulty { get; set; }
    public String Duration { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MinDuration { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MaxDuration { get; set; }
    public String Seasonality { get; set; }
    public String EquipmentLevel { get; set; }
    public String TrailMarking { get; set; }
    public String URL;
    public bool HasTrailType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Type != TrailType.Undetermined;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (((HikingTrail)obj).Name == this.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = hash * 23 + Name.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Type.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + StartPoint.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name.ToString();
    }
}
```

EDIT :
I profiled the db on *dbContext.HikingTrails.Include(x => x.MountainRange).Where(x => x.MountainRange != null).ToList();* and the generated query is OK, meaning it has a Name column for MountainRange as well.

P.S.: several fields are null, but those ones don't have data yet.

Comment: Could you show us `HikingTrailContext`?

Comment: yes, have added it into my post. Thank you for answering

Comment: Can you show us your HikingTrail model?

Comment: yes, thank you for answering

Comment: edit, so elements of dbContext.HikingTrails.ToList() in fact have MountainRange null. I don't know why, it was set before.

Comment: @Răzvan did you try debugging? Can you load the `MountainRange` field even from a unit test? I'd bet not which makes this an EF Core context configuration issue, not an ASP.NET serialization issue. BTW why implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like this when there's a key already?

Comment: @Răzvan where does `MountainRange` come from? How would EF guess how to load it? Does it come from another table? Are there any related records available? Did you try executing the generated query directly?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, 
with "dbContext.HikingTrails.Include( x => x.MountainRange).ToList()" it does load. Have check with debugger.

Comment: have written my current solution bellow. If I find another one I will write again

Answer (score 0):

found one solution, **Projection** to an anonymous type. Also had to be careful not to have two fields with the same name of "Name"

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public dynamic HikingTrails3()
{
    var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HikingTrailContext>();
    dbOptions.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = HikingApp");
    var dbContext = new DAO.HikingTrailContext(dbOptions.Options);

    var trails = dbContext.HikingTrails.Include(x => x.MountainRange).
    Select( i =>new { Name= i.Name, MountainRangeName = i.MountainRange.Name, i.Duration,
    i.Dificulty,i.EquipmentLevel, i.Seasonality, i.Type }).ToList();
    return trails;
}
```